# What is the meaning behind the scene where Saki fights a Tainted Cat?

Tags: from-the-new-world

In Shinsekai Yori episode 10, Saki encounters a Tainted Cat which attacks her in the neck, but fails to damage her due to a necklace she's wearing. While the cat is biting the necklace, she mumbles some words and after that the cat is killed.

The first impression I had was that she was defending herself. So she probably chanted something related to the way the cat was killed. But re-watching the scene, the cat had blood on its mouth despite not being able to damage Saki. What's the meaning behind this scene? What is Saki mumbling? Did SHE kill the cat or was it somebody else (like Shun)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Saki used her skill - restoring object. She was seen training earlier fixing vases and stuff in school. This ability allowed her to fix the broken necklace (for a while), during the attack and heal herself.

I believe that the point was to strengthen the reference that Saki has the same (unique) ability as Tomiko Asahina and is capable restoring own cells and even their telomeres. This is only made clear later by Tomiko Asahina herself, saying that she plans to make Saki her heir, somewhat base on her ability.

Comment: but did she kill the cat? her powers included twisting the cat the way it did?

Comment: I think Saki did. Shun was quite far away. Most characters had quite some skills by then.